# Conditionally open different cursor and perform same action

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Based on user input, my program need to open different cursor but performing same action. As cursors will be getting data from different tables, i am not able to combine the query into one, or use parameterized cursor. Is there anyway we can perform below action without using refcursor?

```
DECLARE
    p_cond      NUMBER;

    CURSOR c1 IS 
        SELECT 'a' txt FROM dual;   -- table A

    CURSOR c2 IS
        SELECT 'b' txt FROM dual;   -- table B

BEGIN
    p_cond := 1;

    FOR tmp IN decode(p_cond, 1, c1, c2) loop  -- this of course doesn't work
        dbms_output.put_line(tmp.txt);
    END loop;   

END;
/
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your select query will always return the record sets with same structure whether it selects from table A or table B . If that's the case , use of ref cursors will be helpful .

In case your select query may return structurally different record sets too , then
you will have to use dbms_sql .

```
create table a (x varchar2(20)) ;
create table b (x varchar2(20)) ;
insert into a values('A') ;
insert into b values('B') ;

DECLARE
    p_cond      NUMBER;

    Type cur is ref cursor return a%rowtype;
    c cur ;   
    var c%rowtype ;
BEGIN
    p_cond := 0;

   If p_cond = 1 then
     Open c for  SELECT 'a'  FROM dual;   
   else
       Open c for SELECT 'b'  FROM dual;  
   end if ;

   loop 
   fetch c into var ;
   exit when c%notfound ;
   dbms_output.put_line(var.x) ;
   end loop; 

END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i try to avoid refcursor as my query is quite complex and high cost. At last i manage to combine the queries by using union (something i have totally forgotten).